Regularity of solutions in ODE
This is a question my teacher raised in his lecture, but I don't know how to solve it.
For a $C^{k}$ differential system, $k\in\mathbb{N}\bigcup\{\infty\}$,
$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=f(x)$, $x\in\mathbb{R},f(x)\in C^{k}(\mathbb{R})$ and satisfies: $x(t_{0})=x_{0}$.
How to prove that its solution $x=\phi(t;t_{0},x_{0})$ is $C^{k}$ smooth about $t$ and $x_{0}$?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
